# Change Label Location in R pheatmap

Tags: r

I am trying to change the label location from the upper right y-axis on the left side of the plot. Also, I would like to increase its size (It would be nice make the legend the same size as y-axis). Does anyone know how to do this? Below is my code and current state of the plot. Thanks!

```
library(pheatmap)
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
rownames(data)=data\[,1\]
data_matrix=as.matrix(data\[,2:11\])
data_matrix\[is.na(data_matrix)\]=-6
pheatmap(data_matrix, cluster_rows = FALSE, cluster_cols = FALSE, legend_breaks = c(-2,-3,-4,-5,-6), legend_labels=c(-2,-3,-4,-5,NA))]
```

[image]

Comment: The position of the legend looks pretty hardwired into the code. (See in particular the last few lines of `pheatmap:::heatmap_motor`, which specify the placement of the viewport into which the legend is drawn.)